# How do you edit CSS in Laravel?

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-blade

Laravel noob here, I'm developing in Homestead.

Right now, if I want to edit something in my CSS, I edit app.scss(located in resources/assets/sass) then recompile my css with Mix. (npm run dev)

I don't know if this is the correct way to edit your css, but the last time I edited something, it worked. But now it doesn't and I'm confused.

I would also appreciated it if someone would tell me what's the use of _custom.scss and _variables.scss in sass folder.

Comment: use `sass --watch` command to generate your css

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct way. However, you need to run `npm run dev` each time you make changes to the app.scss file. Better way is to use `npm run watch` which can keep watching changes to your script files.
`_variables.scss` and `_custom.scss` files are called partial files. It is a convenient way to organize code. In care you want to use partial files. You will have to import them in app.scss file `@import 'partials/variables'`. Though you have to be careful about the order you import the partial files, in case you are using variables and mixins as they need to be imported first before other partials.

For more information checkout the [sass documentation](http://sass-lang.com/guide) or [this treehouse video](https://teamtreehouse.com/library/css-to-sass/refactoring-with-sass/breaking-the-style-sheet-into-partials)

Comment: Thanks, you saved me.